# How to access any control of an Activity from a broadcast receiver. Without using "static"

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I want to access controls of an activity from a broadcast receiver without using "static" or having any data pass between them. I just want to access it directly as in static but without defining any class as static.

In this example I am trying to change the text value of TextView control from broadcast receiver.

```
namespace App2


[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private BluetoothManager bluetoothManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothDeviceReceiver _receiver;
    private TextView currentCharacterName;

    int count = 0;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        Button ChangeTextButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        currentCharacterName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

        ChangeTextButton.Click += delegate {
            currentCharacterName.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++);
        };
        var appContext = Application.Context;

        bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager)appContext.GetSystemService(BluetoothService);
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.Adapter;
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null || !bluetoothAdapter.IsEnabled)
        {
            bluetoothManager.Adapter.Enable();
        }
        _receiver = new BluetoothDeviceReceiver();
        RegisterReceiver(_receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ActionFound));
        bluetoothAdapter.StartDiscovery();
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    private class BluetoothDeviceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            var action = intent.Action;

            TextView currentCharacterName = MainActivity.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            if (action != BluetoothDevice.ActionFound)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Get the device
            var device = (BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);

            if (device.BondState != Bond.Bonded)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Found device with name: {device.Name} and MAC address: {device.Address}");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem occurs here

```
TextView currentCharacterName = MainActivity.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
```

> Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

What kind of reference does it need ? Is MainActivity not a reference ? Is there any other MainActivity around ? I have defined this receiver inside the MainActivity so whenever MainActivity gets an instance , this receiver will belong to that instance. I really do not understand clearly what is going on here. I tried to use the Context which is passed to receiver but I couldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and you shouldn't.  You have no assurance an Activity is running when a BroadcastReceiver runs.  If you need to do that, your application is misarchitected.  The only case where its ok is if the BroadcastReceiver is registered in the Activity and in that limited case you can either make the BR an inner class of the Activity (in which case it can access any variable of the Activity) or it can be passed the control when you instantiate it via its constructor.  But either way is dangerous, as either way can cause it to fire after the activity is finished if you're not careful about unregistration.

Do not under any circumstance make a view a static variable.  Not only will it be wrong (there doesn't have to only be 1 instance of an Activity at a time), but it will cause a memory leak of the entire Activity and all associated variables.

Comment: 0


Yes exactly , As i mention in my question i dont want to use it as static. So ;

1-) what is the correct way of it? 2-) There is a context which is passed to BroadCastReceiver .So that context , i think ,belongs to the MainActivity ,doesn't it? If so can we get the TextWiev control's text by using that context?

Comment: The context passed to a BroadcastReceiver is just a Context.  It doesn't have to be any particular context.  Most likely its the Application context, but don't depend on that.  Like I said-  the only way you can do this is IF the receiver is registered in the Activity, and then you need to pass it in the constructor.  If its a manifest registered receiver or registered in a service you can't-  at all.

Answer (score 0):

I could get the result as i desired  by using this code in BroadcastReceiver ;

```
TextView currentCharacterName = ((Activity)context).FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
```

I created the Broadcastreceiver in mainactivity and de-register it in mainactivity too in case of onPause or other status which is related with deactivation of activity.
I dont claim this is the most secure and best way but at least it changes the text of text view in activity without any exception or error. 
Best regards.

Comment: If you are creating the `BroadcastReceiver` in the `MainActivity`, then you can pass a reference to `MainActivity` when you create the `BroadcastReceiver` (in the constructor). Then you can just call `FindViewById()` on the reference.

Comment: I have created Broadcastreceiver both in and out of the MainActivity , both of them works as desired. But then, A question come up to me, where does that Context  come from to onReceive? Apparently that context is belongs to the my Mainactivity ,but why ? Since event broadcaster is not my MainActivity , why is that context belongs to my Mainactivity ? "_receiver = new BluetoothDeviceReceiver();" During the creating an instance of  BluetoothDeviceReceiver or registration,is the mainActiviy's context passing to that instance  ?  because i did not pass any reference manually to it.